# Intercept access to DOM by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanted to know how do I intercept a DOM access by a JavaScript. Are there any tools or whitepapers available on this ? (Else I will need to write one!)

The idea behind the interception is something to do with a security module for web browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: It's going to be impossible to block access to DOM methods and properties in any way good enough for security purposes. JavaScript is a highly dynamic language with potentially many ways around whatever roadblocks you might put in place.

Comment: You will need to dig deep down in the browser code. What do mean by "*module*", do you have any extension api in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is use [DOM mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents). There are various events such as `DOMNodeInserted`, `DOMNodeRemoved`, `DOMAttrModified` etc (see the DOM events spec, linked to above). There is a general catch-all event called `DOMSubtreeModified` that is fired after any individual DOM mutation; this event bubbles, so you can set a listener on the document to be notified of all changes to the document's DOM.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(evt) {
    console.log("DOM mutation", evt);
}, false);
```

These events are supported in most recent browsers, with the exception of IE (up to and including version 8) and Opera, which supports some evenbts but notably not `DOMSubtreeModified`.

Comment: I don't think (or at least can't imagine) that the OP wants to write his security module in JS.

Comment: @Bergi: Agreed. I think I misinterpreted the question.